# cant unzip file in GCP jupyterlab notebook: 'End-of-central-directory signature not found.'

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-lab

I am running python 3

I am trying to unzip my train.zip dataset on a GCP notebook instance, however whenever I try to I get a various error:

First I tried:

```
import os 
from zipfile import ZipFile

os.path.exists('/home/jupyter/kerasProject/original_dataset/train.zip')
True

zip_file = ZipFile('/home/jupyter/kerasProject/original_dataset/train.zip')
```

Error:

```
BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Then I tried:

```
!unzip '/home/jupyter/kerasProject/original_dataset/train.zip'
```

Error:

```
Archive:  /home/jupyter/kerasProject/original_dataset/train.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /home/jupyter/kerasProject/original_dataset/train.zip or
        /home/jupyter/kerasProject/original_dataset/train.zip.zip, and cannot find /home/jupyter/kerasProject/original_dataset/train.zip.ZIP, period.
```

For some reason in both cases it does not recogise the file as a .zip file, I tried reuploading it but it doesn't help, I can unzip it on my mac no problems so I don't think it can be corrupt, what have I done wrong?

Comment: 1) How did you upload the file? 2) Download and compare to the original. This often tells me what is wrong by looking at the differences.

Comment: So I downloaded it and I get an error telling me 'unable to expand 'train.zip' (Error 2: no such file or directory), it is also 1/100th the size of the original ZIP which tells me that uploading the file using the 'uploads file' option on jupyterlab is not going to work. How else could I upload this ZIP? This file contains several thousand images of cats and dogs, is converting them to a csv file the only option?